# postgres insert the exception error into the table

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, postgresql-9.4

How can insert exception message on table in below query

```
 do $$ 
   begin
    Select (2 / 0) 

 exception when others then 

    RAISE INFO 'Error Name:%',SQLERRM;

    RAISE INFO 'Error State:%', SQLSTATE;

    Insert into TB_ERRORLOG(msg) values('Error =' || SQLERRM || SQLSTATE);
  END;

 $$ language 'plpgsql';
```

Comment: a) end the `SELECT` statement with a semicolon b) don't forget the `END` at the end of the block c) don't quote `plpgsql`.

Comment: Above statement for insert error message is correct statement.

Comment: Then you should be fine!

Comment: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "when"
LINE 5:  exception when others then

Comment: I told you about the missing semicolon...

Comment: Yes done thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The following is the fixed statement.

```
 DO $$ 
  BEGIN
    SELECT (2 / 0); 

EXCEPTION WHEN others THEN 

RAISE INFO 'Error Name:%',SQLERRM;

RAISE INFO 'Error State:%', SQLSTATE;

INSERT INTO TB_ERRORLOG(msg) VALUES ('Error =' || SQLERRM || SQLSTATE);
 END;

 $$ language plpgsql;
```